# Correct way to do a use case diagram with different user types

Tags: java, android, diagram, use-case

I am doing an android application that has two types of users, doctors and patients. 
For the most part they do the same thing but in certain activities they do different things. 
For example, in the calendar activity, the doctor fills out available appointment times they have, whereas the patient fills out their medications in their calendar. 
In my use case diagram I have put the steps each user type takes in separate sections. Is this the correct way to do it or should I just do one section that has one actor called 'user' that outlines the generic tasks they share. 
[Click here to see my use case diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Qr2O.jpg) 
Any feedback is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Your diagram seems more like a workflow, not a Use Case. Use Cases are at a very high level of abstraction. Also, they are purely Functional decompositions of the application, where you should avoid making premature design decisions. A Use Case shows the different actors that are involved and the actions they want to perform. Making them takes a systematic approach to ensure no bits of functionality are missed.

Important elements in a Use Case Diagram are:

- The various actors using the application, including those responsible for the 'backend' and maintenance.
- What the actors actually want to accomplish as the main Use Cases.
- All derived Use Cases that are necessary to implement the main Uses Cases. I prefer the `<<includes>>` relationship to show this. There may be several levels of derived Use Cases.
- The re-use of Use Cases between various other Use Cases.

You should avoid:

- OO-type inheritance and other OO relationships. These will cause you to make premature design decisions.
- Workflow. Use Cases are independent of how the actor triggers them. Workflow is actually a design decision, to be made long after Use Case analysis.
- Blocks that don't actually do anything, like your 'Home' blocks. Use Cases are functional blocks, you must be able to define what information goes in, what information goes out, and what transformations it performs.

To fix your diagram, you should focus on the core functions the users want to perform. For the patient, that would be e.g. "Book Appointment", "Edit Medicine Schedule" and "Communicate with Doctor". Then you should break these up into smaller use cases using `<<include>>`. For example, the "Book Appointment" use case should include showing the calendar and choosing a day.

Have fun!